# jQuery param dynamic object name

Tags: javascript, jquery

why can't i have a variable in an object? I get an error like:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this"
```

My code is like this.

```
$("#search_options input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
  var params = { 
    $(this).attr('name') : $(this).val(),
  };
  var str = jQuery.param(params);
});
```

I'm sure that $(this) is working because I tried to console.log it outside the params object then i is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object literals cannot have variable property names. You'll have to assign the property like so:

```
...
var params = {};
params[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
var str = jQuery.param(params);
```

Comment: ic, didn't know that object literals can't have variables. thanks for info

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use value of a variable as a property name, you must use this syntax:

```
var params = {}

params[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
```

The literal notation, that you're trying to use, expects property name to be a valid JavaScript identifier.

Comment: thanks, didn't know that i can't use variables in object literals